# How do I pull the thumbprint out of a SSL certificate FILE (not the windows cert store)?

Tags: powershell, ssl, ssl-certificate

I understand how to get the thumbprint of a certificate that's installed to a certificate store, however I'm hoping there is a way to get that information from a certificate FILE.

So for example I'd have c:\temp\mycert.com.cer... how would I get the thumbprint from that file? Is it even possible? Google isn't being very helpful. I've been doing this in powershell as such to get this from the certificate store, but again - I need to get this info from a certificate FILE.

```
$certCN = mysite.com
$cert = Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My -Recurse | 
  where {$_.subject -like "*CN=$certCN*"} | 
  where {$_.ExpiringInDays -lt "91"}
$thumbprint = $cert.thumbprint
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I figured this out. First, you need to use openssl, which isn't ideal but that's all I could figure out - still hoping someone will know how to do this natively in Windows. Second, in the Linux (and thus openssl) world, the thumbprint is referred to as the "fingerprint." Finally, the fingerprint is returned in a xx:yy:zz format, so you need to reformat it to make it a continuous string.  This is the openssl command:  $fileThumbprint = openssl x509 -in "$cert.crt" -fingerprint -noout...  write-host $fileThumbprint... SHA1 Fingerprint=25:2E:1F:A3:B6:2C:C4:60:75:5B:07:34:9C:E5:4D:3F:EE:84:45:BF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using a third party library you can rely on [`x509certificate2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx) cryptography class of .NET framework:

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("D:\mycertificate.cer")
$cer = [system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2]::new($content)

$cer.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName
$cer.Thumbprint
$cer.Subject
```

Then you will receive a result like:

```
sha1RSA
5A6008B61ABADE6412BEE4704C2407D5DE5DAA34
C=GB, O=University College London, OU=Computer Science, CN=FTAM Service
```

Comment: You can also pass password in constructor, if the file is protected by a password.